# How to write Junit test case for listener callback in android studio?

Tags: java, android, junit

I'm new in JUnit test. How to test with 100% coverage for listener callback in given code.
I have the following (example) structure within my Android app which I'm trying to write a unit test for. Please help me out.

```
public class FilterHelper {
public static final int NONE = 0;
public static final int ERROR_ONE = 1;
public static final int ERROR_TWO = 2;
public static final int CHAR_LIMIT = 10;
private errorListener errorListener;

public interface errorListener {
    public void onError(int errorType);
}
public void setListener(errorListener listnener) {
    errorListener = listnener;
}
public InputFilter[] getInputFilter() {
    InputFilter[] nameEditInputFilters = new InputFilter[1];
    nameEditInputFilters[0] = getTexttFilter();
    return nameEditInputFilters;
}
public InputFilter getTexttFilter() {
    InputFilter.LengthFilter filter = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(CHAR_LIMIT) {
        @Override
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
            CharSequence result = super.filter(source, start, end, dest, dstart, dend);
            if (result != null) {
                errorListener.onError(ERROR_ONE);
            } else {
                for (int count = 0; count < source.length(); count++) {
                    if (isEmoticonsPresent(Character.UnicodeBlock.of(source.charAt(count)))) {
                        errorListener.onError(ERROR_TWO);
                        return "";
                    }
                }
                errorListener.onError(NONE);
            }
            return result;
        }
    };
    return filter;
}
private static boolean isEmoticonsPresent(Character.UnicodeBlock unicodeBlock) {
    return (unicodeBlock == Character.UnicodeBlock.HIGH_SURROGATES
            || unicodeBlock == Character.UnicodeBlock.MISCELLANEOUS_SYMBOLS
            || unicodeBlock == Character.UnicodeBlock.DINGBATS);
}
```

}